# How can I cancel an input request

Tags: python, printing, console

I am working on adding support from sort of a user console in my program where they can type commands in the python file in the form of `var = input("Input here: ")` however it seems you cannot print thinks while asking for input and I want to it print certain updates to the console...

Is this even possible?

EDIT: I found out enough to narrow down the question to:

How can I cancel an input request

Comment: Would you be able to clarify further what you want to be able to perform? Your provided code will return a string with the user input. If you wanted the user to be able to run commands based on their input you can run `eval(var)` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run any code while waiting for user input in a single thread. You may want to look at the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and create a thread that waits for user input and one to print items. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8kfys3/running_code_while_waiting_for_user_input/) may help.

```
import threading
import Queue

myQueue = Queue.Queue()

def getUserInput():
    return input("Input here: ")

inputThread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: myQueue.put(getUserInput()))
inputThread.start()

while inputThread.is_alive():
    # Your code here
inputThread.join()
var = myQueue.get()
```

Comment: i will try this, gonna let you know if it works

Comment: may i ask, what is the point of the queue module? i am relatively familiar with threading but have never heard of that

Comment: When you are multithreading, you need to be wary of two threads accessing or writing to a variable at the same time. The queue module is designed to provide a safe way to communicate variables between threads. I use it here because it is what I am most familiar with regarding moving variables between threads.

Comment: yeah, the constant text was writing to the input

Comment: wait is there a way to cancel an input request?